# Xcode Bundle Out of Date

Tags: ios, iphone, version, xcode5

An email from apple to its developers said that you could start submitting apps to them for iOS 7. O I have Xcode 5 DPS Version 5.0 (5A11365x) And it says that the version bundle is to old to accept apps for approval. How will this work now because apple said it all would be possible?

Comment: Or wait for a few hours for the public release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use developer preview version which does not allow to submit app to app store.

Update your XCode to official 5.0 version. (From [Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12)).

Answer (score 0):

In order to submit apps to the App Store, you will need Xcode 5.

Submission to the App Store for iOS 7 requires Xcode (build 5A1413 and above).

If you are using any of the Xcode 5 Betas (including the GM Seed), upgrading is necessary. You can either upgrade through the App Store, or download the .dmg through the Apple Developer Portal at developer.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the latest version of Xcode 5, which is now the fully released version on the store?

Answer (score 0):

Hope my answer may help..

Its not must actually even you can still submit your apps with iOS6.x version build with your Xcode 4.6.3.

What they trying to convey in that mail is, they are just letting you know that you can now start submitting iOS7 app because there is whole lot of new thing out there with iOS 7.0 sdk.

When I try to convert my iO6.x version to 7.0 with Xcode 5 i didnt face any problem on building or submitting the app.